# Mimic org-capture for seting variables

Tags: elisp

I like the way `org-capture` works, it promotes a buffer for selecting
predefined templates. I am trying to do something similar for setting
variables.

For example, I have three HTML themes, one for office, one general
use, and one for journal. I am trying to define a
`choose-html-themes()` function which has similar behaviour.

I defined a list of options,

```lisp
(setq html-themes-list 
  '((Office . "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" ..... " )
    (General . "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" ..... ")
    (Journal . "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" ..... "))
```

When I call `choose-html-themes` function, then type

- "o" to set the /entry/ variable to "Office"
- "g" to "General"
- "j" to "Journal".

Then it will look up the list using *entry* as key, and set
the *org-html-head* variable to the returning value, something like

```lisp
(setq org-html-head (assoc entry html-themes-list))
```

I wonder how to popup a buffer, and capture keyboard input from that buffer?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question but have you tried using the `hydra` package to do something similar?

Comment: @kaushalmodi I tried using `hydra`, it can solve the problem, but `complting-read` is more elegant for this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `completing-read`.  See `C-h f completing-read`.

```el
(let* ((user-input  (completing-read "Theme: " html-themes-list nil t))
       (theme-link  (cdr (assoc user-input html-themes-list))))
  (DO-SOMETHING-WITH theme-link))
```

Comment: Great! I have been looking for this function for a long time! Compared with `hydra`, I like it more for providing the keys of the list as the selection candidates and I can use `helm` to choose. Very handy function. Thank you very much!

Comment: I hesitated to write this answer because you specifically asked for `org-capture` stuff. But it seemed that this does correspond to what you were really trying to do, so I posted it.